# Deploy Django to Heroku - Push rejected

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

Please redirect to the **UPDATE 2** section of this question :)

I am trying deploy my Django application to heroku and I get an error when I perform `git push heroku master command`

Do you know the reason which I get this error?

```
(uleague) ➜ pickapp git:(master) ✗ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 195, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (92/92), done.
Writing objects: 100% (195/195), 516.34 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 195 (delta 93), reused 195 (delta 93)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: 
remote: ! Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote: to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/a...
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to shielded-crag-57385.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/shielde...
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shielde...
(uleague) ➜ pickapp git:(master) ✗
```

I have the following structures directory:

[image]

I follow the [getting started tutorial for deploy in heroku web page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#prepare-the-app) and in their samples, the requirements.txt and the settings.py were as a isolated files in the root project and not nested under folders as a settings/ folder or a requirements /folder

This have related for my error of push rejected ?

**UPDATE 1**

I try create a `requirements.txt` file and inside it the line `-r requirements/production.txt`

Of this way my structure directory already stayed:

[image]

And the content of requirements/production.txt is:

```
-r base.txt
gunicorn==19.4.5
dj-database-url==0.4.0
```

And I get the same error:

```
(uleague) ➜  pickapp git:(master) ✗ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 195, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (92/92), done.
Writing objects: 100% (195/195), 516.34 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 195 (delta 93), reused 195 (delta 93)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to fuupbol.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fuupbol.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fuupbol.git'
(uleague) ➜  pickapp git:(master) ✗ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 195, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (92/92), done.
Writing objects: 100% (195/195), 516.34 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 195 (delta 93), reused 195 (delta 93)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to fuupbol.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fuupbol.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fuupbol.git'
(uleague) ➜  pickapp git:(master) ✗
```

I don't know some solution to this. :(

**UPDATE 2 - Current Situation/challenge**

My error was that I do not make `commit` operation before the pushing ...
Sorry for the newbie situation ...

I make `commit` and the deploy process was starting, but now I have the following error related with my `SECRET_KEY` environment variable

When I perform `git push heroku master` my console get:

```
nf/__init__.py", line 120, in __init__
remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
remote: 
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !    Push rejected to fuupbol.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/fuupbol.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/fuupbol.git'
(uleague) ➜  pickapp git:(master) ✗
```

With respect to SECRET_KEY error

```
 nf/__init__.py", line 120, in __init__
    remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
    remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

I have different settings for my project, taking in account different environments.  The structure directories is:

```
pickapp/pickapp/settings/base.py
pickapp/pickapp/settings/development.py
pickapp/pickapp/settings/production.py 
pickapp/pickapp/settings/testing.py
```

In `pickapp/pickapp/settings/base.py` I have setup the SECRET_KEY variable of this way:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
def get_env_variable(var_name):
    try:
        return os.environ[var_name]
    except KeyError:
        error_msg = "Set the %s environment variable" % var_name
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)

SECRET_KEY = get_env_variable('SECRET_KEY')
```

This is because in my operating system (VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/postactivate of virtualenvwrapper directory configuration) I have something like this

```
export SECRET_KEY="*/****"
```

In `pickapp/pickapp/settings/development.py` (**which inherit from `base.py`**) I have setup the Databases  variables of this way: 
development.

```
from .base import *

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': get_env_variable('DATABASE_NAME'),
        'USER': get_env_variable('DATABASE_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': get_env_variable('DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

# Update database configuration with $DATABASE_URL.
import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=500)
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

And my `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is of this way:

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="pickapp.settings.development"
```

Althought `pickapp/pickapp/settings/development.py` inherit from `pickapp/pickapp/settings/base.py` in which the `SECRET_KEY` variable is managed by my `get_env_variable()` function described above

Now, all this that I described, is related with my local development environment machine, Should I tell to Heroku how to find the value of my environment variables encypted?
I think so ...

With the respect to the `collectstatic` error

```
Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
remote: 
remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
remote: 
remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
```

Should I perform `collectstatic` command before to make `git push` command?
My static files I have them n amazon s3

Any orientation about of this will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try creating a `requirements.txt` in project root which simply includes `-r requirements/production.txt`

Comment: @v1k45 Please, can you see my **UPDATE 1** that I've put in my original question. I don't understand the reason by dows not works ...

Comment: did you run `$ heroku create --buildpack heroku/python` before pushing?

Comment: @v1k45 My error was that I don't perform the commit operation before the push. Sorry, but now I have the following situation described in the **UPDATE 2** section, just in case that you want support me. Thanks :)

Comment: @v1k45 I already setup my different environment variables in heroku cloud platform according to this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application :) Now I am reviewing the django static files topic

Comment: make sure your static files settings matches this configuration https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

Comment: @v1k45 it's true. My deployment works. Thanks Mr. :D

Comment: @v1k45 I have this error now, in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36272067/deploy-static-assets-to-heroku-from-local-machine-cant-open-file-manage-py?noredirect=1#comment60171440_36272067 If you can check and help me I will be grateful.